# Defined url in virtual host not working on remote server on windows azure

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssh, virtualhost, azure

I created a virtual host for http://staging.layzer.tunde.com and the url is not pointing to the page directory but if I enter the file path as in http://ip/staging.layzer.tunde.com 
I can view the page. I enabled the site with the command sudo a2ensite staging.layzer.tunde.com.conf

Please what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the hostname in DNS if you want it to work.  It does not work at the moment:

```
$ host staging.layzer.tunde.com 
Host staging.layzer.tunde.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

If we can't lookup the hostname, there's nothing to magically translate it into an IP.  If fixing your DNS is out of your control, you can temporarily hack this by adding the IP and hostname into your `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: by adding IP do you mean my local IP address or the IP of the remote server?

Comment: You need the hostname to resolve to your server's address in DNS.  `staging.layzer.tunde.com` needs to resolve to your server's IP.

Comment: I did something like this in /etc/hosts: 154.47.31.570 staging.layzer.tunde.com. Yet it is now working. 154.47.31.570 refers to my server's ip

Comment: Cool.  Remember, that fixes it only for your machine.  If you want to fix it for the rest of the internet you need to update DNS.

Comment: Pardon me if am bordering you but what I mean to say earlier is yet it is not working. Am so sorry, I can't figure it out. Am new to sys administration

Comment: According to [whois the admin for your domain is "Baba Olaogun"](http://whois.icann.org/en/lookup?name=tunde.com).  Have you asked them to add your IP to DNS?

Comment: eventually done! I appreciate your contribution.